# Byte Displacement in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVHBj.png

I'm attempting to find the 1-byte displacement for some jumps. 
What I got was:

```
26
7
7
29
```

Not sure if I did that right though, any help?

Comment: That's not enough information, we can't tell without knowing the addresses (for both the labels and the jumps).

Comment: We cannot tell if you don't say where the labels `done`, `next1`, etc. are...

Comment: I think all of the local telepaths and black magicians are on vacation today. Seriously, you are giving some chunk of information brutally torn out of any context and expecting for an answer?

Comment: @Jester added the assembly code, I forgot it, my apologies

Comment: Why is the code a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offset is relative to the next instruction, you do not need to add the current instruction's length. In other words, the offset encoded is in addition to the normal increment that the cpu does for going to the next instruction. Which is why your first three answers are off by 2 each. Should be `0x24`, `5` and `5`.

For the last one you counted right, but forgot to negate the result because it's a backwards jump. Thus, the answer is `-41` (decimal) which is `0xd7`.

PS: you could have typed that into an assembler and verified the offsets yourself.

Comment: I had a feeling they'd be off by two but I wasn't completely sure. Much appreciated for the help though!